# Making translator able to translate more then one language

Tags: ruby

**UPDATE: Fixed the argument error, by removing `elsif input.include? != false` on elsif and replacing with `elsif input == false`**

**UPDATE2: Code is working perfectly, translates precisely and gives correct translations to phrases**

```
require 'yaml'

def translate
    translations = YAML.load_file 'spanish.yml'

    puts "Enter word or phrase to be translated to English, press 'Q' to quit:"
    input = gets.chomp
    case
    when translations[input]
        puts "The translation to English is: #{translations[input]}"
    when input =~ /q/i
        exit
    else
        puts "Invalid word or phrase redirecting..."
        translate
    end
end
translate
```

Is there a way I could make the translator also be able to translate from Russian? Here's the Russian YAML file:

```
и: and, though
в: in, at
не: not
он: he
на: on, it, at, to
я: I
что: what, that, why
тот: that 
быть: to be
с: with and, from, of
а: while, and, but 
весь: all, everything
это: that, this, it 
как: how, what, as, like
```

Would I do the same thing as translating from Spanish but instead of loading Spanish would I load `russian.yaml` or would I have to make another definition such as:

```
def russian_translate
  translations = YAML.load_file 'russian.yml'
  puts "Please enter the phrase to translate"
  etc...
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant by `input.include? != false`, but `include?` requires a parameter.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Would you mind elaborating a little more? Could I do `.include?(false)` to return it as non existent?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this should be a new operator syntax, that will be introduced in Ruby3: `?!=`, meaning “not sure if it is equal to.” :)

Comment: @mudasobwa
 lol, I updated the post, I realized I was being an idiot :)

Comment: Please specify a condition you want to use to print “Invalid ...” in plain English. `input` is always a string, since it came from `stdin`, it makes no sense to compare it against `false`.

Comment: @mudasobwa So would I compare it to the hash instead?

Comment: Comparison of string object against hash object makes no sense either. Please just describe what do you want to achieve.

Comment: It isn't necessary, or particularly desirable to add "Update #1..." comments. Instead, add the needed information inline, as if it was part of the original document to maintain the readability of the question. If necessary we can see when and where something was changed.

Comment: @the Tin Man I am sorry, I was just trying to keep the post updated

Comment: We appreciate the idea, but, like I said, it's possible for us to tell when there's been a change, and even see what changed. Stack Overflow isn't a forum or discussion group. Instead, we are helping create an online book of programming questions and answers. Think of how you see text books written; SO is a little less formal, but it's still similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one probably should not put a hash, written with Ruby syntax, in text files. Ruby guys commonly use [YAML](http://yaml.org/) for that:

es_en.yml:

```
a: to
abajo: down
el_abanico: fan
```

Then one might load this file into a hash:

```
require 'yaml'
translations = YAML.load_file 'es_en.yml'
#⇒ {  
#    "a" => "to"
#    "abajo" => "down"
#    "el_abanico" => "fan"
# }
```

It’s time now to deal with `input`:

```
input = gets.chomp
case
when translations[input]
  puts "The translation is: #{translations[input]}"
when input =~ /^q$/i # input is a single “q” letter
  exit
else "Translation not found"
end
```

You might want to put this in the loop.

Comment: Just wondering: why would you use a regex for matching a single letter q, instead of simply `input == 'q'`? In terms of readability it's worse (hence the need for a comment). What's the advantage?

Comment: @Mischa Because that way it will not matter about how the letter is spelt, you could also just do:

`when input =~ /q/i`

It will make it so that they can put in "q" or "Q"

Comment: It's not "ruby guys" who use YAML, it's anyone who wants an easily read, serialized representation of that object/data that can be reused by multiple languages. "ruby guys" are just like "python guys", "perl guys" or "java guys" that way.